# Print correct time on a zshrc command

Tags: bash, shell, zshrc

I currently have this code snippet running in my zshrc for an alias where the terminal is supposed to print "Last pushed at ${current time}", laid out below

```
# custom var 
d=`date +%I:%M`
# aliases
alias gpo="git push origin && echo Last pushed at $d"
```

the problem is that currently it prints the time as whenever the window last loaded the .zshrc file. For example, if I run `source ~/.zshrc` at 3:30pm, and then run `gpo` at 3:45pm, the console prints "Last pushed at 3:30".

The only way I've gotten it to work so far printing the correct time is `alias gpo="source ~/.zshrc && git push origin && echo Last pushed at $d"`.

Is there a better way to write this alias so that it actually prints the correct time every time the alias is run?

Comment: The alias gets the timestamp of the time the whole script is executed (i.e. sourced), not the time when the timestamp is run. I'm also a bit confused, why you call this file `.zshrc`. While you can name your files the way you want, this file has a specific meaning to zsh, but you say with your tags that you are running bash.

Comment: Why the `bash` tag if it is a `zsh` question?

Answer (score 0):

@Author,

Initially you set the value for "d" to
d=`date +%I:%M`
Later you are using same variable $d
Hence I tested related update using my system:
`` $ alias gpo='d=`date +%I:%M:%S`;echo git push origin && echo Last pushed at $d'

$ gpo

git push origin

Last pushed at 07:54:40

$ gpo

git push origin

Last pushed at 07:54:45 ``

Answer (score 0):

Use the `date` command directly instead of that `$d` variable:

```
alias gpo='git push origin && date "+Last pushed at %I:%M"'
```

For zsh use the `print` builtin to show the date:

```
alias gpo='git push origin && print -rP -- "Last pushed at %D{%I:%M}"'
```

For bash >= 4.1 use the `printf` builtin:

```
alias gpo='git push origin && printf "Last pushed at %(%I:%M)T\n" -1'
```